# Clarification about what this convergence arrow means.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am wondering what it means $\searrow$ means.

If I have that $a_n$ is a sequence and $a_n\searrow 0$. I assume this means that the sequence is only of positive numbers or non-negative numbers? But does it also mean that the sequence is monotone?

Answer (score 2):

I interpret that to mean 
the sequence is monotone decreasing.